# can be NULL same as 0000-00-00 in a nullable DATETIME column while selecting rows?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am working on some PHP code optimization and while I am going through I find some SELECT statements with the following conditions:

```
WHERE `date_exported` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR `date_exported` IS NULL
```

This makes me wonder whether the same statement will work the same with only one condition: the comparison to NULL or the comparison against an "invalid" datetime.

I will add on top of that: using MySQL Workbench and Datagrip (or the equivalent from tools like PhpStorm) I am not able to see the column with `NULL` but `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. I am not sure if this is a configuration thing or if it is supposed to be like that.

This is MySQL 5.7  <s>and I do not have permission to check on config stuff or insights on how this instance is configured.</s>

I have tried to set a playground [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/e9KR6E42) but it won't allow me to add `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in a NULL `datetime` column

The `SQL_MODE` is set as follows:

```
NO_ZERO,IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Note: is it `0000-00-00 00:00:00` invalid at all?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "SQL_MODE";`  And look for `NO_ZERO_DATE`.

Comment: Added to the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "SQL_MODE";` And look for `NO_ZERO_DATE`.

It would be more efficient to avoid `OR`.

Consider "fixing" the data during `INSERTs`.  This avoids the need to hassle it during `SELECTs`.

Since the default is `NO_ZERO_DATE`, I recommend moving that direction.  cf https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_show_old_temporals

I don't have the details on this shift away from "zero_date", so I can't say where 5.7 fits in to the spectrum.

I don't know whether you can do (1 column at a time).

```
UPDATE t
    SET mydate = NULL
    WHERE mydate = '0000-00-00'
```

and similarly for any datetimes.

I tried using something like your WHERE .. OR .., but I got `ERROR 1525 (HY000): Incorrect DATE value: '0000-00-00'`.  But then I have `NO_ZERO_DATE` set.

I hope I have pointed you in the right direction; sorry to not have the full Answer.

Comment: I can fix new data as you recommend but what about existing one? I need to keep both sides on the WHERE condition, right?

Comment: Give me an example of "both sides".

Comment: Oh I meant the WHERE condition with `0000-00-00 00:00:00` AND `IS NULL` I need to keep both of them because of old data that I might be unable to update or it can cause chaos in the system

Comment: @ReynierPM - I added more to my Answer almost as fast as you added Comments.

Answer (score 1):

> This makes me wonder whether the same statement will work the same
> with only one condition: the comparison to NULL or the comparison
> against an "invalid" datetime.

No, the same statement will not work for both cases.

`null` is an unknown value , while `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is a known value.

Null can only be evaluated by using `is/is not null` , while `0000-00-00 00:00:00` can be evaluated by using `=`,`<>`..etc.

---

> Is it 0000-00-00 00:00:00 invalid at all?

From [The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html#:%7E:text=MySQL%20retrieves%20and%20displays%20DATETIME,23%3A59%3A59%27%20.)

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
> parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
> hh:mm:ss' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
> '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

I would say is invalid, maybe it represent an unknown value which would be better using null instead.

---

**What I suggest for better performance ?**

Change the table structure to the following and update the values .

```
`date_exported` DATETIME DEFAULT  NULL
```

Please keep a backup before using the following method.

If you are using InnoDB storage Engine use

```
SET autocommit=0;

LOCK TABLES some_table WRITE; 

create temporary table some_table_new ( `date_exported` DATETIME DEFAULT  NULL );

insert into some_table_new  select case when date_exported='0000-00-00 00:00:00' then null else date_exported end from some_table;

truncate some_table ;

insert into some_table select * from some_table_new;

drop temporary table some_table_new;

COMMIT;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

In the query keep only the following condition, an index on  `date_exported` is sufficient.

```
WHERE `date_exported` IS NULL
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/TEvR-BxW)

Comment: (See also `<=>` for testing for `NULL`.)

Comment: Instead of `truncate+insert`, do `rename+drop`; it will be immensely faster.